# How do I set the content of a tab view item in swift

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I created a tab view in storyboard, and created an outlet in my code, and every time a user clicks a button, it creates a new tab item that has a web view in it. I have not found a way to set the content of the tab programatically. Is there some way to set the content of the tab item?

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var tabView: NSTabView!


@IBAction func addTab(_ sender: Any) {
        let newTab = NSTabViewItem()
        //newTab.setContent(webView)
        tabView.addTabViewItem(newTab)
    }
```

There's also another problem. When I try to create a new tab with the addTab function, I get an error :

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: You might want to add the Mac tag to your question. Most Swift questions end up being iOS related these days, and the way tabs and tab view controllers work is different between Mac and iOS.

Comment: Try setting the `viewController` or `view` property of the tab view item.

Comment: I too am struggling with TabViews.  I'm working on a Preferences window using TabViews.  You might want to look at this link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raLK95FyQso

Comment: After another look, I think you have to init NSTabViewItem with a viewController.  Another helpful tutorial is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bndz6cHbGEw